# Как в атрибут value тега input занести if (empty($_POST['...'])) echo $_POST['...'];?

Tags: php, form, форма

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
         $errors = array();

         if (empty($_POST['name'])) $errors[] = "name";
         else $name = trim($_POST["name"]);

         if (empty($_POST['email'])) $errors[] = "email";
         else $email = trim($_POST["email"]);

         if (!empty($errors)) {
             echo "Ошибка! Пожалуйста, укажите ";
             foreach ($errors as $error) echo " - $error";
         }
         else echo "Форма отправлена! Спасибо, $name.";
     }
     else {
         echo 
         '<form action="" method="POST">
         <p>Имя:
          <input type="text" name="name" value= "' . if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
          echo $_POST['name']; . '">
         </p>
         <p>Email:
          <input type="text" name="email" value="' . if (empty($_POST['email']))
          echo $_POST['email']; . '">
         </p>
         <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>';
     }
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Выдает ошибки syntax error, unexpected 'if'  
Вопрос: как мне в value занести if (empty($_POST['...'])) echo $_POST['...'];

Comment: `<input type="text" name="name" value="' . (empty($_POST['name']) ? '' : $_POST['name']) . '">`

Comment: Во-первых, не ленитесь ставить фигурные скобки, вы за них не платите никому и ничем, а "читабельность" они увеличивают здорово.. По второму пункту ошибся.. `if (!empty($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name']; }`

Comment: @Эдуард выодит ошибки:

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\Веб-формы с сохранением данных.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\Веб-формы с сохранением данных.php on line 36

Comment: Скорее всего надо писать echo $_POST['...'];

Comment: Но выводит ошибки:

Comment: echo( string $arg1 [, string $... ]): void
syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: @JustLearn потому что криво используете - [см.пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46dc6d6ef53d503d27604dc6a9a48cb8c396442b)

Comment: @InDevX не понял как и куда вставлять фигурные скобки. Можете пожалуйста объяснить поподробнее? Да, на счёт второго пункта ошибочка вышла) Я случайно вместо isset написал empty))

Comment: да везде у вас их нет.. `if (empty($_POST['email'])) $errors[] = "email";
         else $email = trim($_POST["email"]);` - непонятная куча кода, вместо `if (empty($_POST['email'])) { $errors[] = "email";
         } else { $email = trim($_POST["email"]); }`

Comment: `C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\Веб-формы с сохранением данных.php` - никогда не называйте файлы кириллицей да ещё и с пробелами...

Comment: @InDevX ок, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
         $errors = array();

         if (empty($_POST['name'])) { 
            $errors[] = "name";
         } else { 
            $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
         }
         if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $errors[] = "email";
         } else {
            $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
         }
         if (!empty($errors)) {
             echo "Ошибка! Пожалуйста, укажите ";
             foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo " - $error";
             }
         } else {
            echo "Форма отправлена! Спасибо, $name.";
         }
     }
     else {
    ?>
         <form action="" method="POST">
         <p>Имя:
          <input type="text" name="name" value= "<?= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '' ?>">
         </p>
         <p>Email:
          <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '' ?>">
         </p>
         <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>
     <?php }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```